# Can a corporation be a minor?

Tags: india, incorporation, age

If a law defines a minor as a legal person below (some age) does this mean all corporations not incorporated before (some age) years are minors? If yes who are their guardian?

Comment: Could you cite the law you're referring to?

Comment: This question is quite clear, and should not be closed. It just makes an incorrect assumption about. the law One of the functions of this site is to correct such mistaken beliefs.

Answer (score 6):

### The law doesn’t “defines a minor as a legal person below (some age)”

It defines it as a **natural** person below (some age).

Comment: I think this answer needs to describe the difference between a "legal" person and a "natural" person, and also have at least one reference to "the law" that states this.